# shall I use Spring framework for a performance-critical proxy application?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, servlets

I've created a servlet (Tomcat) application which has these functions:

- It performs HTTP Basic Authentication. It connects to a user and role database.
- It works as "security facade" for some geodata servers behind
- It forwards requests after doing some authorization tests
- In case the response contains XML data, it performs some manipulation (changing URLs, deleteting some XML-Elements or changing it's content). I'm using STaX for this task.
- It logs some information about the response to a database.

It's likely that there is a need for connecting to another user database and to extend the capabilities of the authorization components.

The size of the response data reaches form 10 kB to 500 MB.

I'm new to Spring. Shall I introduce the Spring framework in my application?

**EDIT:**
Perhaps, this question is better: is there a framework (Spring for example) which causes minimal performance loss?

**EDIT 2:**
Is the SO community "Programmers" a better place for this question?

Comment: Questions like this will generate mainly opinionated answers.

Comment: Having a "reference" implementation I see no hindrance as I think the changes to cost some time but be simple. Apache shiro might be an option too. As to performance: instead of filter/servlet I have often seen server integration. That is more specific code, and might change on the next server version. But should be feasible for simple authentication.

Comment: @Ulrich which is still off-topic as asking for resources, tools etc. is considered off-topic.

Comment: @JoopEggen - thank you. I've noticed Apache Shiro before, but it seems there is not much activity in the project.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you plan to rewrite all your existing code to fit into spring (might be a valid approach)? Or do you want to add spring as an additional dependency so you can make use of it somewhen in the future (meh).

Comment: Question with the latest edit is now primarily opinion based.

Comment: @atamanroman - rewriting my existing code is an option

Comment: @M.Deinum - is the SO community "Programmers" a better place for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before re-writing your code first thing you should analyze is why do you require Spring framework? What problem are you facing in your current architecture?

Just because size of the response data stokes up shouldn't be the only reason to re-write your code. You can better design your existing code to scale your application.

On the flipside the primary upside of writing your code in Spring is it will cut down the boiler plate code for an instance you don't have to explicitly write code for creating JDBC connection with database every now & then rather you would use the Spring JDBC template. Spring facilitates features like [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) which would require you to write less code.

Also a framework is written keeping in mind all the performance optimization issues so definitely Spring will help in reducing the latency of your app.